# How determine largest reflected number

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I was trying to  determine maximum number from list of given integer in problem 8 [here](http://www.naec.ge/images/doc/documents/GRE-2007-ILIAUNI-math.pdf) (page 5).

So as you see, there are 5 written numbers on paper, and on the wall there is a hanging mirror.  We should determine which row contains the largest integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers (as we see them in the mirror) are 
$$8800008$$
$$8008808$$
$$8000088$$
$$8888808$$
$$8008008$$
A mirror flips left and right, so the actual numbers on the paper are
$$8000088$$
$$8088008$$
$$8800008$$
$$8088888$$
$$8008008$$
Clearly, the middle one (row number 3) is the biggest.

Comment: A mirror doesn't flip left and right; see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8227/a-mirror-flips-left-and-right-but-not-up-and-down.

Comment: @joriki: That's a good point; I guess the correct description is just that the page is reflected, though this seems kind of circular / definitional.